# PayPal "Buy Now" Link?

Tags: paypal

I see in PayPal how to make a Buy Now button. However, the code behind that is a form that POST to PayPal. Is there a way to create a link to a PayPal payment page with all of the relevant information (e.g. item name, price, custom customer fields to request, discount coupon field, etc.)? I want to be able to include this link in emails/SMS. I only have one item to sell and it's for a certain price, unless a valid discount coupon is applied, then it's for a set lower price.

I will want to put a Buy Now button on my site to do the same thing, but I do need a link I can email/SMS as well. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, PayPal website payments standard URLs work via either GET or POST, so you can take the same variables and put them in the URL string. So for example:

`https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=foo@yourcompanyhere.com`

However, I'm not sure if this is an "offical" feature; while it has worked for at least the last dozen years so I would be comfortable using it in an email, I would recommend keeping your primary website integration using form posts.